# Javascript: Loop through each line and remove until a specific character

Tags: javascript

This is my log that I want to process:

```
2017-07-03  15:10:40.945    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need
2017-07-03  15:10:40.946    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need2
2017-07-03  15:10:40.947    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need3
```

Currently it works only on the first line:

```
var myText = '...'
var preProcessed = myText.substring(myText.indexOf("|") - 3);
```

Results (only works for the first line):

```
LOG| Here comes the text I need 
2017-07-03  15:10:40.946    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need2 
2017-07-03  15:10:40.947    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need3
```

How can I loop line by line to have at the end again a text without the date and time?

Comment: Show what you've tried.

Comment: looks like you want the word `LOG` too so why not start from there, also you got to tell us more, are these logs in a file and each of them is a line in a file?

Comment: Split by new line separator and apply this function to every item in array.

Answer (score 0):

You could split by new line, remove the text you don't want, then join it back. So something like this.

```js
var log = `2017-07-03  15:10:40.945    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need
2017-07-03  15:10:40.946    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need2
2017-07-03  15:10:40.947    Host -> LOG| Here comes the text I need3`

var preProcessed = log.split("\n").map(function (l) {
   return l.substring(l.indexOf("|") - 3);
}).join("\n");

console.log(preProcessed);

// you can also use regex like this
var preProcessedUsingRegex = log.replace(/.*->\s/g, '');
console.log(preProcessedUsingRegex);
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for explaining both options. As a beginner I had to find explanation on the regex pattern, maybe this helps: .* matches any character (except for line terminators.
'->' matches the characters ->
\s matches any whitespace character (equal to [\r\n\t\f\v ])

Comment: @gmrenard you're welcome! Glad you found the explanation of the regex. Please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You should get your array of lines first, and then doing what you want.
Something like this:

```
var lines = text.split('\n');
lines.forEach((line) => {
  console.log(line.substring(line.indexOf("|") - 3))
})
```